# Knockout JS - Observable becomes undefined when added to an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object called `purchase` that gets put into one of two observable arrays depending on its status. The `purchase` object has an observable called `integrationStatus` that I default to a css class name of `integration-status--complete`

For some reason the purchases in the Scheduled array are coded green as expected but the purchase in the Unscheduled array throws an error as `integrationStatus` is undefined

Thanks in advance

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbAAK/yu1xsnnz/56/)

Comment: You are binding `viewModel` object to view, so should it not be `someVariableNameThatHoldsPurchaceObject.integrationStatus`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please create a [MCVE] so that other users can reproduce your issue. `Array1`, `table2`, foo, bar are rather confusing and will lead to us making assumptions about your code as @Rajesh is making in the above comment. How are you using the `foreach` binding? How are you *"moving"* from one array to the other?
It would really easy to help you if you can create a minimal [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @adiga. This is my first post so I appreciate the comments. Have added a fiddle as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the mapping configuration within `Schedule`. The mapping call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { scheduleDays : scheduleDayMapping }, self)` instructs the utility to only customize the mapping of the `scheduleDays` object from the `data` variable.

Since that configuration doesn't include an entry for `unallocatedHolder`, the mapping utility uses the default observable creation behavior instead of the custom behavior. The `UnallocatedHolder` function is never called, so its `purchases` array doesn't get the custom mapping. Without that mapping, `integrationStatus` is not defined for those purchases.

I'd suggest defining a new mapping configuration for `Schedule` like this:

```
var scheduleMapping = {
  "scheduleDays": scheduleDayMapping,
  "unallocatedHolder": {
    create: function(options) {
      return new UnallocatedHolder(options.data);
    }
  }
};
```

Then, reference this new mapping configuration within `Schedule` by updating the mapping line to

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, scheduleMapping, self);
```

[Revised Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devonfreitas/abwh5ed0/)

Comment: Awesome Devon, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!